# How to use local .txt files in a Shiny App

Tags: r, file, shiny, shinyapps

Hi all this is my first question, so I hope the format is correct.

I'm looking to create a R shiny app that calls on all the .txt files that that are within the parameters set by the user, merges those .txt files, and produces a word cloud.

The app located here https://lukaszsowinski.shinyapps.io/WC-app/ crashes once it is opened, although it works on my local computer. I'm almost sure it has to do with the way I'm writing in my wd(), data files, and .txt files as they were giving me problems before I was able to finally published. This is the error I'm getting

**2017-08-12T01:17:22.742107+00:00 shinyapps[204302]: Error in loadWorkbook(file) : 
2017-08-12T01:17:22.742109+00:00 shinyapps[204302]:   Cannot find /home/shiny/WC-app/WordMappingInfo.xlsx**

Here is the ines of code that I'm not sure where my error is.

```
library(rsconnect)
rsconnect::deployApp('C:/Users/Lukasz Sowinski/Desktop/WC-app')

server <- function(input, output, server) 
{

textframe <- read.xlsx("C:/Users/Lukasz Sowinski/Desktop/WC-app/WordMappingInfo.xlsx", 1)

schooldata <- list (
    "Num" = textframe$Num[!is.na(textframe$Num)],
    "SchoolName" = C(textframe$SchoolName),
    "Path" = c(
        "C:/Users/Lukasz Sowinski/Desktop/WC-app/texts/Queens College.txt",
        "C:/Users/Lukasz Sowinski/Desktop/WC-app/texts/Lehman College.txt",
        "C:/Users/Lukasz Sowinski/Desktop/WC-app/texts/Denison University.txt", 
        "C:/Users/Lukasz Sowinski/Desktop/WC-app/texts/St Johns University.txt",
        "C:/Users/Lukasz Sowinski/Desktop/WC-app/texts/Rutgers University.txt"
    ),
    "Students" = textframe$Students[!is.na(textframe$Students)],
    "Tuition" = textframe$Tuition[!is.na(textframe$Tuition)],
    "Program" = textframe$Program[!is.na(textframe$Program)]
)
```

Here is the some of the cod where I call up the data as needed based on user input.

```
if (schooldata$Program[i] == input$selection)
                {

                    if (temptext == 0)
                    {
                        temptext <- schooldata$Path[i]
                        temptext.1 <- readLines(temptext)
                        mastertext.1 = temptext.1
                    }

                    temptext <- schooldata$Path[i]
                    temptext.1 <- readLines(temptext)
                    mastertext.1 <- rbind(mastertext.1, temptext.1)

                }
```

I've also tried using pathways
"./WC-app/WordMappingInfo.xlsx"
"~/WC-app/WordMappingInfo.xlsx"
That I found in similar questions but neither work.

Any help would be tremendously appreciated. Thank you

Comment: You're pointing the code to a file on your local computer which shinyapps.io does not have access to.  Complicating the situation is that on shinyapps.io you don't know where the folder is. You could try "~/texts/Queens College.txt"

Comment: Try "./texts/Queens College.txt"    Also I would get rid of all spaces in names since linux does not like them.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with shinyFiles CRAN packages extension?

In the ui.R file

```
shinyUI(bootstrapPage(
    shinyFilesButton('files', label='File select', title='Please select a file', multiple=FALSE)
))
```

In the server.R file

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    shinyFileChoose(input, 'files', root=c(root='.'), filetypes=c('', 'txt'))
})
```